# Code to create a new task in task list for each user from people picker

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Can any one let me know how to add a new task for each user from people picker.

For example In my people picker i have 3 users (john,kevin,Tom).I want to create 3 separate tasks in task list for these users. I want it through Code.Can any one help me on the same.

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: Are you creating the Tasks using Workflow.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get selected user's from people picker field,

```
//Get the collection of users from people editor  

SPFieldUserValueCollection srvcRepCol = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(); 

for (int index = 0; index <= this.peopleEdControl.ResolvedEntities.Count - 1; ++index)
{ 
      PickerEntity objEntity = (PickerEntity)this.peopleEdControl.ResolvedEntities[index];
      srvcRepCol.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(srvcWeb, Convert.ToInt32(objEntity.EntityData["SPUserID"]), objEntity.Key));
}
```

[Code Reference 1](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-get-and-set-the-value-of-a-people-editor-control-programatically-in-SharePoint--960.php)

Now get user's using this code and create a task for them

```
foreach(SPFieldUserValue uValue in srvcRepCol)
{
   using(SPWeb web = new SPSite("url").OpenWeb())
   {
         web.EnsureUser(uValue.User.LoginName);
         SPUser user = web.SiteUsers[uValue.User.LoginName];
         SPList oTaskList = web.Lists[GUIDid];
         SPListItem oTaskItem = oTaskList.Items.Add();
         oTaskItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = "";
         oTaskItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Priority] = "(2) Normal";
         oTaskItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo] = user;
         oTaskItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Description] = "";
   }
}
```

**Note**

Some of Code is hand written so watch out for typo mistakes.